# Prestashop multi stores different servers

Tags: prestashop, multistore

Is it possible to do (read is there viable solution for) Prestashop multiple front ends in different servers ? Like shop1.com served from 1.1.1.1 and shop2.com from 1.1.1.2 (different servers), yet having same backend in server 1.1.1.3 OR in one of the storefront server ?

I have googled yes, but have not found any good solution to this.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.teapotcreative.co.uk/blog/how-to-setup-prestashop-multi-store) article, near the bottom it describes how to setup multistores on different domains.

Comment: @TheDrot no it's not. Diamonte is asking for multi stores over different servers not domains.

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop includes the possibility to have your database over multiple SQL servers (a master database and slaves). But I can't see how you could have multiple apache instances (how to handle cache files, uploads...), or you should just have multiple Prestashop websites over multiple servers...

---

**If your want to configure database slaves:**

To use Database slaves server you need to edit file `/config/db_slave_server.inc.php` and `/config/defines.inc.php` (in this file you need to edit this define to `1` `define('_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_', 1);`).

Then when using a SQL query you can define if you want to run it on the slave or master database `Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS("SELECT 1");`. Most internal classes and modules already uses this configuration.

Comment: Well I guess one approach is to install fully prestashop to each server, and use external DB which is shared between them (prestashop has already multistore (handle products for different stores etc)? I have currently 2 stores and one coming up, so I thought if I could split em, just in case if one goes down others are still up. Thought this is just an idea yet, current servers are pretty stable anyway and scaling is easy so I'm not sure if its worth the efforts to split em.